# How do i make a button call a function?

Tags: javascript, function, button

I'm new to coding and i need some help. I have a start button `<button id="startBtn" onclick="draw()">START</button>` i want this start button to call my draw function

```
    function draw() {
    drawWalther();
    rain();

    if (rightPressed && (waltherX + waltherWidth) < 865) {
        waltherX += waltherDx;
    } else if (leftPressed && waltherX > -54){
        waltherX -= waltherDx;
    }

    if (y + dy > c.height - 100 || y + dy < 0) {
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (rightPressed && (waltherheadX + waltherheadWidth) < 900) {
        waltherheadX += waltherheadDx;
    } else if (leftPressed && waltherheadX > 50){
        waltherheadX -= waltherheadDx;
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
} 
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

but of course when i load the game it loads the draw function without me having to click the start button
so how can i make the function get called when i click the start button and not when i reload the game

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) for us.

Comment: Remove the `onClick` attribute and then add this: `document.querySelector("#startBtn").addEventListener("click", draw})` and finally remove the last line `requestAnimationFrame(draw);`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the function `draw` as a handler in the function `requestAnimationFrame`, so the function `draw` it's being called automatically.

Embrace function `addEventListener` and bind the event `click` as follow:

### 1. Remove the onClick attribute

```
function draw() {
  drawWalther();
  rain();

  if (rightPressed && (waltherX + waltherWidth) < 865) {
    waltherX += waltherDx;
  } else if (leftPressed && waltherX > -54) {
    waltherX -= waltherDx;
  }

  if (y + dy > c.height - 100 || y + dy < 0) {
    dy = 0;
  }

  if (rightPressed && (waltherheadX + waltherheadWidth) < 900) {
    waltherheadX += waltherheadDx;
  } else if (leftPressed && waltherheadX > 50) {
    waltherheadX -= waltherheadDx;
  }
  x += dx;
  y += dy;

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
document.querySelector("#startBtn").addEventListener("click", draw));
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `requestAnimationFrame(draw)` immediately after you define the function. This runs the function immediately and thus doesn't wait for the button. If you remove the instance that is AFTER the function definition, it will wait for the function.

Simplified example:

```
<script>
function draw() {
    // some code
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};
</script>
<button onclick="draw()"></button>
```

Your new code:

```
<script>
    function draw() {
    drawWalther();
    rain();

    if (rightPressed && (waltherX + waltherWidth) < 865) {
        waltherX += waltherDx;
    } else if (leftPressed && waltherX > -54){
        waltherX -= waltherDx;
    }

    if (y + dy > c.height - 100 || y + dy < 0) {
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (rightPressed && (waltherheadX + waltherheadWidth) < 900) {
        waltherheadX += waltherheadDx;
    } else if (leftPressed && waltherheadX > 50){
        waltherheadX -= waltherheadDx;
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
} 
</script>
<button id="startBtn" onclick="draw()">START</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really appreciate it :)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by pressing the flag. Happy to help!